# How to fix the POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 417?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

**Trying to:** publish an customized bot through visual studio 2017. Once i publish it, I get to see the first message from the bot. However, after my input message, I fails with the error message  as "**There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code ExpectationFailed**" in Bot channel.

I am publishing a web bot app with bot framework SDK-3 in MS Azure portal.

[image: See Image for detail error message: Exception in MS Azure App Insight]

**Tried:** installing different package versions (including latest 4.2) for bot.builder and bot.connector, however, it gave more errors like "**type or namespace name IDialog<> could not be found**"

**Expectation:** What could be all the potential scenario for such error and is there any helpful reference?

Comment: You are talking of SDK v3 and then Bot Builder packages 4.2. In which version of the SDK is your code made of?

Comment: @NicolasR  the bot was build using bot builder/connector package of 3.14.1 .  what I mean from sdk-3 is, while creating the **web app bot** from azure portal, I choose sdk-3 however there is also an option of sdk4. Also, when i just published without upgrading I was getting an error as ** "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code ExpectationFailed"

Comment: So 1st thing; if the bot was build using bot builder/connector package of 3.14.1, you should not use a package 4.X

Comment: @NicolasR true my bad. Now, with packages with version 3.14.1, locally it works fine tested with bot emulator. However, after i publish to azure replacing the **default web bot app** with the custom bot (visual studio), i get an error  as "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code ExpectationFailed" in the bot channel. what is it referring to?